# d3 svg drawing rect bar chart not work in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, d3.js, svg, internet-explorer-11

I'm finish a dynamic bar chart using d3, it's perfect work in google chrome.

However, it's not work in IE11.

here is [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/a04qu38y/1/)

The problems are:

1. only work on drawing the background table, but the bar charts are not work.
   Here is the actual situation in IE 
   [My code run in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxOHj.png)

   You can see that the first part, drawing the background are perfectly work in IE, however the barchart were missed and run without any error.
2. I use `svg.polygon` to draw the star, and I divide draw stars code into two parts: first part I draw inside the table(over the bar chart), second part I draw outside the table, used to be legend.

The star in legend can print as usual, but all stars in table were missed and IE give the error code:

```
SVG4602: SVG Point list has incorrect format and could not be completely parsed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my question.

The problem cause by the code

```
linear((new Date(d.collect_date) - starttime)/cal_hour+16)
```

In IE, it can't run the code `new Date(d.collect_date)` because of some date setting( I guess)
So in this case, linear(...) this code won't return anythings, it finally not print out any bar chart.

So I have found the method to change the way to get date, and it success print the bar chars, and the stars in table is same problem.

So I change all get x location method into:

```
var temp_x = d.start.split(" ");
            var temp_y = temp_x[0].split("-");
            var temp_z = temp_x[1].split(":");
                return linear((new Date(new Date(temp_y[0],(temp_y[1]-1),temp_y[2],temp_z[0],temp_z[1],temp_z[2])) - starttime)/cal_hour+16);
```

It's work on both chrome and IE